# discrete names for tuple method parameters

Tags: typescript, tuples

I have to define a method, that by restriction can only be called with one parameter (a Subscriber). I need to pass several values, so I group them in a tuple.

In the subscriber, I would like to access each variable of the tuple as its own name. So I am looking for syntax like

```
([name:string, age:number, salary: number]) => {
  console.log("our name is " + name);
}
```

Does typescript support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array de-structuring syntax:

```
([name, age, salary]: [string, number, number]) => {
    console.log("our name is " + name);
}
```

Comment: yep, that's what I found too

Comment: @f.khantsis You can't have explicit names for tuples entries in any other way